# YouTube Data API v3 does not have unique IDs for resources

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

This is befuddling me and seems a bit ludicrous. When I execute two different queries on the Data API (take the example request on the [Activities List endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list) as a proof of concept) the `id` for resources are not the same between requests.

Here's an activity resource from my first request:

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#activity",
    "etag": "\"RmznBCICv9YtgWaaa_nWDIH1_GM/uGfbHYfKHEFhxWYbbmVxyBbQvNk\"",
    "id": "VTE1MjI3NzQwODY5NDMzMzYyOTc5NjQ5Ng==",
    "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2018-04-03T16:48:06.000Z",
        "channelId": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
        "title": "Google Summer of Code 2013 Mentor Summit",
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Note the `id` value, which is "the ID that YouTube uses to uniquely identify the activity" according to the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#id).

Here's my second request:

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#activity",
    "etag": "\"RmznBCICv9YtgWaaa_nWDIH1_GM/dzIxWbnYZ3xx-1zi2VQ0V_f5PII\"",
    "id": "VTE1MjI3NzQwODY5NDYzMDM0OTg5MDAwMA==",
    "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2018-04-03T16:48:06.000Z",
        "channelId": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
        "title": "Google Summer of Code 2013 Mentor Summit",
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

The `id` is different for the same resources. Although first few characters are the same, I've tried to truncate the `id` but it's still not unique for all resources.

**I'm wondering if the `id` is the de facto way to uniquely identify resources. Has anyone run into this? Is this the proper behavior? How do I uniquely identify resources if the `id` that YouTube provides is not the way?** I could put together a hacky solution, but this doesn't seem right.

Would love to hear thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used was to take the hash of the publish date of the activity and the channel ID appended together. This does not sit well with me, but it's the solution I went with.